# Algorithm for fast array comparison and replacing elements with closest value. (Tracking Points)

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stl, tracking

I have two arrays currPoints and prevPoints.  Both are not necessarily the same size.  I want to compare each element in currPoints with prevPoints and replace the value in prevPoints that is closest to the value in currPoints.

Example:

```
prevPoints{2,5,10,13,84,22}
currPoints{1,15,9,99}
```

After applying the algorithm

```
prevPoints{1,5,9,15,99,22}
```

So what is the best algorithm/method for this?  It needs to be fast.

**Context**: If it helps, I am trying to work on a tracking algorithm that takes points from two consecutive frames in a video and tries to figure out which points in the first frame correspond to points in the second frame.  I hope to track objects and tag them with an ID this way.  Speed is crucial as processing is to be done in realtime.

Comment: Are points sorted? Is binary search fast enough for you?

Comment: If two points in previous are both closest to the same currentPoint, do they each morph to the same point or only the closest one? Does the other simply stop or does it find the nearest other point outside such things?

Comment: @Tatarize The other one has to be ignored.  I want one point per blob and if blobs merge, they should turn to one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to sort both the arrays first. But remember the original orientation of the prevPoints array as you need to get the original array again at the end.

So after sorting:

```
prevPoints{2,5,10,13,22,84}
currPoints{1,9,15,99}
```

Now you basically need to figure out which of the **currPoints** should get into **prevPoints**. The algorithm is will be similar to **merge 2 sorted arrays** just that you won't merge, instead replace values.

Initially both pointers are at the start of the corresponding arrays. 1 from currpoints should replace 2 in prevPoints based on the fact that the value in currPoints is less than prevPoints and you know that the next points in PrevPoints will only be higher than 2 (sorted arry, remember). Replace and move on the pointers.

Now currpointer is at 9 and prevpointer is at 5. Calculate the absolute difference and keep a store of the minimium absolute difference encountered so far and also the value of the number that caused the least minimum absolute difference to be encountered.(4 in this case). Move the prevpointer forward as the currpointer is pointing to a higher value.

Now prevpointer at 10 and currpointer at 9. 9 is less than 10 and so a replacement has to be done. As this minimum absolute difference is less than the earlier one ( 1 < 4 ) so 10 will be replaced by 9.

Now the prevpointer is at 13 and currpointer is at 15.

Proceed in the same fashion.

Rearrange the prevPoints array to the original orientation.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: brilliant mate!  Will try this and get back if I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0):

We sort the first list by the x positions, and the second list by the y positions. So each point has a position in each list. Now the way you do this for a nearest neighbor search (at least what I came up with) is you find the position of the point in each list through a binary search. Then we know 4 directions, either +-1 x or +-y, and basically we travel in each of these directions until such time as the best length so far is greater than the distance of just that one coordinate.

So we search in the each direction. And say the closest point is at a distance of 25, then if our next coord in the +X direction is beyond 25 in just the +X direction we can stop because even if the change in Y is 0, it cannot be closer.

This makes for a highly effective and quick n(log(n)) closest point algorithm to find a single point. But, also since we only need the two sorted lists once we have those in n(log(n)) time we can find the nearest point for all the remaining points in something like log(n) time. Find the position in the x sorted list, find the position in the y sorted list. Then spiral out until you truncate and have certainly found the nearest point. But, since the scaffolding is the same in each case it should simply end up being quite quick.

Though given your actual test case you might want to come up with something that is simply a very effective heuristic.

---

Simply tracing the points seems really naive, if we are tracing the same thing from frame to frame it should be the case that the point from F0 to F1 in F2 should actually be equal to the distance it travelled in F0 to F1. If we assume all these points are traveling in roughly straight lines, we could do a much better job than simply closest points. We could find generally the curves these points are taking. If we guess that their position should be `F2 by interpolating F0 and F1 and low and behold the position of a point there is really really close. Then we can be quite sure we nailed that.

Equally the objects one would assume have all the points travel roughly the same direction. Like each point travels +5,+5 from F0 to F1, not only can we guess their positions of F2 but we can know these objects make up the same object rather effectively.

Comment: The video is inside a conference room and people are not moving outside the frame for a long time.  I want to keep an eye on them for as long as they stay.  I want to count the occupancy.  The issue with simple blob counting, is that when people are stationary for a long time, the BG MOG technique I am using for bg subtraction removes them from foreground.  If I can track those blobs and remember the last known position, I will still keep counting them until they move out of the room.

Comment: Require they all wear big green balls on their foreheads. Problem solved. :)

Comment: Yeah, if you can spot them as people and find their general position, it should be pretty easy to just find the nearest point from last frame to this one. My method up there would certainly work, and you could well keep the sorted list from frame to frame if they aren't moving much, then when you change the positions of those points and resort it should have to swap roughly 0 points each time and there's plenty of O(n) best case sorting for the algorithms. -- I personally use it for points that are shifted closer each iteration to their nearest point, but you could certainly just track things.